# Porcentagem Com javascript

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, estou com uma dúvida besta e preciso da ajuda de vocês. Tenho uma situação onde preciso exibir se o valor é 25% a mais que o valor atual.
Porem estou com dificuldades pra montar essa lógica. Dei uma pesquisada mas não encontrei algo que me esclarece-se:

```js
var valor_input = 25;
var valorAtual = 50;
var result = DUVIDA;
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode verificar fazendo a divisão por 4 ou multiplicando por 0.25

```
var valor_input = 25;
var valorAtual = 50;

//Dividindo por 4
if( valor_input > (valorAtual/4) ){
    //Aqui você poem o aviso ou um alert
    alert('Maior que 25%');
}

//Multiplicando por 0.25
if( valor_input > (valorAtual*0.25)){
    //Aqui você poem o aviso ou um alert
    alert('Maior que 25%');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa testar se o valor é maior do que 25% do atual ou tem mais de 25% de acréscimo? No segundo caso o valor 25% maior pode ser obtido multiplicando o valor atual por 1.25, ou seja, basta testar se o valor é maior do que o atual vezes 1.25 (ou, se quiser deixar configurável: 1+(acrescimo/100)).

Algo do tipo...

```
if( valor_input > (valorAtual * 1.25)) {
   alert("Você informou um valor com mais de 25% de acréscimo");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Caso você queira saber se o valor inserido sofreu um acréscimo maior do que 25% em relação ao valor atual:

```
var result = valor_input > valorAtual*1.25;
```

Caso queira saber se o valor inserido é maior do que 25% do valor atual:

```
var result = valor_input > valorAtual*0.25;
```

Answer (score 2):

25 % a mais do que o valor atual seria:

```
valorAtual + valorAtual * 25 / 100
```

Então temos:

```
var valorInput = 25;
var valorAtual = 50;
var valorAMais = valorAtual + valorAtual * 25 / 100;

if (valorInput > valorAMais) {
    alert("È 25% maior");
}
```

A fórmula do @PerryWerneck também é válida.